# Prove that the product of the last digit of the number $2^n$ and of the sum of all of its digits but the last is divisible by $3$ .

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that the product of the last digit of the number $2^n$ and of the sum of all of its digits but the last is divisible by $3$ .

Well, the remainds when $2^n$ is divided by $3$ is $1$ or $2$ . Now, what about the sum of its digits excluding the last one...I am not getting it how to calculate it....

Comment: Does this mean to prove that $3| 2^n-2$ for $n \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, $|2^n-4$ for $n \equiv 2 \bmod 4$, and etc. ? Consider the 4 cases and you have what is needed to prove

Comment: @NikolaTolzsek Actually I am not getting u...Well, the question asks for the product of the last digit of $2^n$(i.e. $2^n\equiv r_1(mod 10)$ )which is $r_1$ and the sum of all digits of $2^n$ excluding it's last digit (which is $r_1$  as the last digit of $2^n$) i.e. $S(2^n)-r_1$ where $S(n)$ is the sum of digits of $n$ . It requires to prove that this product i.e $r_1(S(2^n)-r_1)$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: $S(n) \equiv n \bmod 3$, so except for $2^4 \equiv 6 \bmod 10$ and 6 is divisible by 3, instead of finding the remainder of $S(2^n)-r_1=S(2^n-r_1)$ you can actually prove that $2^n-r_1$ is divisible by $3$ when $4 \nmid n$